# NRPE agent works on 1 server, but not on the other, exactly same command

Tags: centos, nagios, nrpe

I have a very strange issue.
It seems that when I execute a `check_nrpe` command to check the load on remote machines, it works on `server1`, but exactly the same command does not work on `server2`, and it returns:

```
Warning threshold must be float or float triplet!
Usage:
check_load [-r] -w WLOAD1,WLOAD5,WLOAD15 -c CLOAD1,CLOAD5,CLOAD15
```

Both machines are similar, CentOS 7. On both machines I installed the NRPE agent as follows:
`yum install nrpe`

and on both machines I installed the `check_load` plugin as follows:
`yum install nagios-plugins-load`

The command is defined on both server1 and server2 in **exactly** the same way, in the `/etc/nrpe.d/commands.cfg` file:

```
command[check_load]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_load -r -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
```

I restart the the NRPE service on both machines after config changes, so that is not the problem. Now the actual NRPE command that I am sending to server1 and server2 is:
`check_nrpe -H server1 -c check_load -a .15,.10,.05 .30,.25,.20`

output server1:

```
OK - load average per CPU: 0.00, 0.01, 0.03|load1=0.000;0.150;0.300;0; load5=0.005;0.100;0.250;0; load15=0.025;0.050;0.200;0;
```

**Exactly** the same command to server2:
`check_nrpe -H server2 -c check_load -a .15,.10,.05 .30,.25,.20`
results in the above warning message!

Executing the `check_load` command locally on server1 and server2, works on both servers.. so this is an issue with NRPE? But then why is server1 working and server2 not..? SELinux is turned off everywhere..

How is this possible?! This does not make any sense!

**UPDATE:**
After I change my `commands.cfg` file on `server2` to:
`command[check_load]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_load -r $ARG1$ $ARG2$`
(removed the -w and -c flags)

and then do this command:

`check_nrpe -H server2 -c check_load -a -w 0.15 -c 0.30`
the status is returned, no warning anymore, but it returns the status of the load in `CRITICAL`.. and if I do the command locally on server2 with the same threshold values, it returns `OK`..
`check_load -w 0.15 -c 0.30`

is this a bug in NRPE?

**UPDATE:**
It seems to have happened before:
https://forums.meulie.net/t/warning-threshold-must-be-float-or-float-triplet/1525

but no solution given unfortunately..

**uPdAtE:**

SoLuTiOn:
The server that is receiving NRPE commands, must allow incoming arguments, so this must be set in `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`:
`dont_blame_nrpe=1`

Solved :P

Comment: what is the status of SELinux on both servers?

Comment: Currently it is `Enforcing`, but I have tried it with both servers `Permissive`, still no difference.

Comment: same version of NRPE? from EPEL?

Comment: Yes: `yum list installed` | grep nrpe` output on both servers: `nrpe.x86_64     3.2.0-6.el7      @epel`